# Batch file over network path

Tags: batch-file, network-programming

I have the following batch script to make life easier at work.

Here is what it is supposed to work:

1- Drag and drop some file onto the .bat
2- Choose file's destination on the "menu"
3- Script copy's files to destination folder
4- Script executes remote procedure (that's the PSexec line)
5- Script copy's the result of the remote procedure to other folders.

And this works fine...  except for a "small" detail with which i need some help.

When i try to copy the network location \10.250.39.116\d%... if i haven't previously logged into that machine it wont work.

I've been looking into the 'net use'  command to overcome this, but i'm not sure if it suits my needs.

There are a total of 4 different machines i need to authenticate, dependent on the choice of the menu.

### Actual Question:

### Can i log in to such machines with the batch, and avoid creating duplicate connections every time i run the script ? If so, how?

Thank you for your time! 
:)

I know the paths I have all point to the same place :)

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion



ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO PRESS 1, 2 OR 3 to select your task, or 4 to EXIT.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Compilar em Qualidade
ECHO 2 - Compilar na HSDEV
ECHO 3 - Compilar nas DEMOS
ECHO 4 - EXIT
ECHO.
SET /P M=Type 1, 2, 3, or 4 then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO :QUAL
IF %M%==2 GOTO :HSDEV
IF %M%==3 GOTO :DEMO
IF %M%==4 GOTO EOF


:QUAL
set "PathForms6=\\10.250.39.116\d$\GLINTTHSIAS\GLINTTHS\compilador\fmb6i\GH\"
set "PathForms10=\\10.250.39.116\d$\GLINTTHSIAS\GLINTTHS\compilador\fmb10\GH\"
set PathCompilador=\\10.250.39.116 -u Administrator -p Password1 cmd "/C d: & cd d:\GLINTTHSIAS\GLINTTHS\compilador & GH_PRIV_10_02_Forms.bat"
set PathDestinoPriv=\\10.250.39.116\d$\GLINTTHSIAS\GLINTTHS\PRIV\GH
set PathDestinoPub=\\10.250.39.116\d$\GLINTTHSIAS\GLINTTHS\PUB\GH
goto :PROCESSA
goto EOF


:HSDEV
set "PathForms6=\\10.250.39.116\d$\GLINTTHSIAS\GLINTTHS\compilador\fmb6i\GH\"
set "PathForms10=\\10.250.39.116\d$\GLINTTHSIAS\GLINTTHS\compilador\fmb10\GH\"
set PathCompilador=\\10.250.39.116 -u Administrator -p Password1 cmd "/C d: & cd d:\GLINTTHSIAS\GLINTTHS\compilador & GH_PRIV_10_02_Forms.bat"
set PathDestinoPriv=\\10.250.39.116\d$\GLINTTHSIAS\GLINTTHS\PRIV\GH
set PathDestinoPub=\\10.250.39.116\d$\GLINTTHSIAS\GLINTTHS\PUB\GH
goto :PROCESSA
goto EOF

:DEMO
set "PathForms6=\\10.250.39.116\d$\GLINTTHSIAS\GLINTTHS\compilador\fmb6i\GH\"
set "PathForms10=\\10.250.39.116\d$\GLINTTHSIAS\GLINTTHS\compilador\fmb10\GH\"
set PathCompilador=\\10.250.39.116 -u Administrator -p Password1 cmd "/C d: & cd d:\GLINTTHSIAS\GLINTTHS\compilador & GH_PRIV_10_02_Forms.bat"
set PathDestinoPriv=\\10.250.39.116\d$\GLINTTHSIAS\GLINTTHS\PRIV\GH
set PathDestinoPub=\\10.250.39.116\d$\GLINTTHSIAS\GLINTTHS\PUB\GH
goto :PROCESSA
goto EOF



:PROCESSA
set argCount=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
   set /A argCount+=1
   set "argVec[!argCount!]=%%~nx"
   set "pathVec[!argCount!]=%%~dpx"

)


rem echo Number of processed arguments: %argCount%


for /L %%i in (1,1,%argCount%) do (

    echo Vou compilar %%i - "!argVec[%%i]!"

if exist %PathForms6%!argVec[%%i]!.* del /q %PathForms6%!argVec[%%i]!.*
if exist %PathForms10%!argVec[%%i]!.* del /q %PathForms10%!argVec[%%i]!.*

robocopy "!pathVec[%%i]!." %PathForms6% !argVec[%%i]!.fmb > nul

) 

c:
cd  c:\pstools
psexec %PathCompilador%


 for /L %%i in (1,1,%argCount%) do (

if exist "%PathForms10%!argVec[%%i]!.fmx" (
 xcopy  %PathForms10%!argVec[%%i]!.fmx %PathDestinoPriv% /y
 xcopy  %PathForms10%!argVec[%%i]!.fmx %PathDestinoPub% /y)
 )

pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much testing have you done with `net use`?  Try running it twice at the command line.  Notice how the output changes at the second running:

[image: session output for net use]

As you can see, where a connection has already been established, `net use` will output a summary of the connection rather than creating a duplicate connection.

---

If you prefer, you could use [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution) or errorlevel checking.  Using this method, you can avoid calling `net use` until `xcopy` fails, which should only be the first time.  Here's a short example, simply to illustrate the mechanics:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

ping -n 1 10.250.39.116 | find /i "TTL=" >NUL || (
    echo 10.250.39.116 is offline.  Unable to continue.  Press any key to exit.
    pause >NUL
    goto :EOF
)

call :xcopy "%~1" "destination"

echo Press any key to exit.
pause >NUL
net use \\10.250.39.116\d$ /delete >NUL 2>NUL
goto :EOF

:xcopy <source> <dest_dir>
xcopy /L "%~1" "%~2" 2>NUL || (
    net use \\10.250.39.116\d$ /user:username password >NUL 2>NUL
    xcopy /L "%~1" "%~2"
)
goto :EOF
```